# Why Does IIS CORS Module 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Appear To Be Cached?

Tags: iis, caching, header, cors

We are attempting to access a cross-origin image file from JavaScript:

```
var testImage = var Image;
testImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
testImage.src = 'https://cdn.example.com/testImage.png';
```

in a browser (Chrome, but we see the behavior on other browsers and directly through curl as well) displaying the same web page content from three different domains. The image server is running IIS and has the CORS module installed with the following configuration:

```
<cors enable="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
    <add origin="https://www.first_domain.com" allowed="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
    <add origin="https://www.second_domain.com" allowed="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
    <add origin="https://www.third_domain.com" allowed="true">
        <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
    </add>
</cors>
```

Whether access is blocked or granted depends on the timing and order of access. For example, if we access the image from https://www.first_domain.com, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value will be 'https://www.first_domain.com' and access is granted, but subsequent attempts to access the image from either of the two other allowed origins will also result in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value being returned as 'https://www.first_domain.com' and access will therefore *not* be granted.

If we wait for four minutes or more and then try to access the image from https://www.second_domain.com, then the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value will be returned as 'https://www.second_domain.com' and access will be granted. However, trying to access the image from https://www.first_domain.com afterward will also result in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value being returned as 'https://www.second_domain.com' and access will be blocked.

Wait four more minutes and https://www.third_domain.com (which has been blocked out all along so far) will then be granted access and https://www.first_domain.com and https://www.second_domain.com will both be blocked. It is as though the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value is being singularly cached for four minutes on the image server the first time someone accesses it, and then that same value is returned for all domains requesting access thereafter until the cache expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cache rules in IIS to ignore/exclude specific headers for specific extensions, either through IIS Manager (via the Output Caching Feature) or directly in the web.config.  You'll wind up with a caching config somewhat like:

```
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" varyByHeaders="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    </profiles>
</caching>
```

Obviously, you can set the policy to whatever invalidation you like; the varyByHeaders is the key element (separate multiple header names with semicolons.)  Certain operations - namely authentication - don't mix well with kernel mode cache, so if all else fails, try disabling just kernel mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to work around this issue by disabling the cache in web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <sytem.webServer>
      <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />
      ...
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Still looking for a better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

When you use CORS, you should also set the following header to avoid caching issues:

Vary: Origin

See the following references:

- [Vary: origin response header and CORS exploitation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151590/vary-origin-response-header-and-cors-exploitation)
- [CORS and Vary](https://textslashplain.com/2018/08/02/cors-and-vary/)